# Change arrow colors in ng-bootstrap carousel

Tags: html, sass, bootstrap-4

I'm creating carousel with ng-bootstrap, I want to change arrow colors or image from white to black cause i have white background images and they are invisible. My problem is that i can't get span, i don't know how to call this in scss. I'm using bootstrap 4 and ng-bootstrap for angular https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/carousel/examples. When i change image url in console it works. I was trying to get arrows directly but nothing happens.

My code:

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
      <div class="imageCarousel">
        <ng-container *ngIf="product.images">
          <ngb-carousel>
            <ng-template id="imageSlide" ngbSlide *ngFor="let image of product.images | slice: 1">
              <img [src]="image">

            </ng-template>

          </ngb-carousel>
        </ng-container>
      </div>
    </div>
```

scss:

```
.imageCarousel {
        max-height: 500px;
        text-align: center;
        color: $color2;
        .carousel .slide {
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            background-image: url("https://storage.googleapis.com/staging.pc-shop-260af.appspot.com/ic_keyboard_arrow_right_black_24px.svg");
        }

        img {
            // border: 2px solid blue;
            max-width: 100%;
            max-height: 400px;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ngb-carousel use SVG images as controls, you can override that with your own image of prev and next button:

```
.carousel-control-prev-icon{
   background-image: url('https://apufpel.com.br/assets/img/seta_prim.png')
}
.carousel-control-next-icon{
  background-image: url('https://apufpel.com.br/assets/img/seta_ult.png')
}
```

Comment: yeah, the problem is i'm not green with scss, and i was trying that and still nothing

Comment: like i said above, 'i was trying to get arrows directly'

Comment: Can you upload a fiddle?

Comment: i have connected this with firebase db, can't :/

Comment: upload an mvp version without the connection, just with the slider.

Comment: and whats with angular ?

Comment: The problem was, i can't style those arrows in my components styles. Global style.scss worked. Anyway your answer work but u can change it to use it global answer and i will accept

Answer (score 9):

Yeap it's solved but you sometimes it's necessary to set the view encapsulation to `None`

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-builder",
  templateUrl: "./builder.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./builder.component.css"],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

Comment: Thanks -- this worked so that I could get local CSS of the icons to work.

Comment: I've tryied your solution and now local CSS works but arrows click don't.

Answer (score 4):

First I would suggest upgrading to ng-bootstrap v6+ which correctly makes the ngb component ViewEncapsulation as None so it can be set through global CSS or via unencapsulated component CSS. See (https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/3479).

Second, override the SVG by simply setting it again & changing the **fill** property to whatever color you desire.

```
.carousel-control-next-icon {
   background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='rgb(50, 54, 57)' width='8' height='8' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3e%3cpath d='M2.75 0l-1.5 1.5L3.75 4l-2.5 2.5L2.75 8l4-4-4-4z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e") !important;
}
```

or alternatively you can invert the colors if you're just looking for more contrast:

```
.carousel-control-next-icon,
.carousel-control-prev-icon {
   filter: invert(1);
}
```

Setting **encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None** on your host component isn't a best practice. The smarter thing to do is to make these entry changes to your projects styles.scss (or whatever is specified in angular.json as the global styles file)

Answer (score 3):

The answer given by Eduardo (above) only works if encapsulation is set to ViewEncapsulation.None which can have unintended side effects on other aspects of your CSS.

Instead the ::ng-deep pseudo-class can be used to target the specific CSS in question. In your scss file use the following:

```
::ng-deep .carousel-control-prev-icon{
  background-image: url('your-replacement.svg');
}
::ng-deep .carousel-control-next-icon{
  background-image: url('your-replacement.svg');
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the tour to learn how Stack Overflow works and read How to Ask on how to improve the quality of your question.

Comment: But according to the documentation of Angular, encapsulaton affects only the current component, so to avoid CSS rules interfering with others, just extract the carrocel to be a separate component.

Answer (score -1):

When inspecting that control on the link provided you can see your two buttons have classes attached to them.

[image: Inspection]

Those arrows have a background-image attribute. Override that class for that attribute in your own css file.

Comment: I'm up from my desk currently. Can you verify that changing the attribute in the inspector works?

Comment: Yeah i've checked, nothing works, i was trying to get to this arrows, directly to them, even call thier parents and still nothing